# Read Json with Beam

Tags: java, json, apache-beam

Is it possible to read "Json" with Apache Beam ?

Actually, I'm reading Text files with `TextIO.read()` and storing the result into `PCollection<String>`.

I would like to know if is it possible to read Json files and store it in `PCollection<Json>` without multiple transfers that wouldn't be very optimal.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to define a json coder/decoder for you beam reader object :

```
class JsonCoder(object):    
    """A JSON coder interpreting each line as a JSON string."""
    def encode(self, x):
        return json.dumps(x)

    def decode(self, x):
        return json.loads(x)

filename = 'data.json'

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    read_data = p | beam.io.ReadFromText(filename,coder=JsonCoder())
...
```